# How do I include a "-" in my code when it is part of a HTML class attribute?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

*I am brand new to Python/Web scraping*

I am currently trying to web-scrape data from a website that has a class attribute of "data-row". However, whenever I attempt to use this attribute it splits data/row in half and shows a problem ("Expected parameter name Pylance). Is there any way to include this "-" in the code?

**Example of code that works**

```
exampleVariable = exampleDocument.find("tr", **id**="0")
```

**Example of code I want to fix**

```
exampleVariable = exampleDocument.find("tr", **data-row**="0")
```

Comment: what packade do you use? beautifulsiup? post [mre]

Comment: I use beautifulsoup.

Answer (score 2):

Use `attrs=` parameter of `.find` function:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_code = """\
<tr data-row="0">Some data</tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, "html.parser")


tr = soup.find("tr", attrs={"data-row": "0"})
print(tr)
```

Prints:

```html
<tr data-row="0">Some data</tr>
```

---

Or: Use CSS selector and `.select_one` method:

```py
tr = soup.select_one('tr[data-row="0"]')
```

Comment: Faster, again. What can I do...

Comment: I changed my code to this but I receive an "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'". Data I'm scraping: <tr id="money" data-row="0"> == $0. My code: moneyData = soup.find("tr", attrs={"data-row": "0"}). I have been able to pull data from this HTML element by using the id, but if I can use the "data-row" it will save me hours. @Andrej Kesely

Comment: @pchryss Probably the attribute was inserted with JavaScript, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. Try to `print(soup)` and see if the parameter is there.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I tried print(soup) and it returned "None". Any way around it? I was able to pull data using the id="money" if that helps.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I apologize I told you the wrong thing. My soup: soup= BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser"). My variable: moneyData = soup.find("tr", attrs={"data-row": "0"}). I did print(moneyData) and it returned "None".

Comment: @pchryss Then try to print the whole document: `print(soup)` and check, if the `<tr data-row="0">` is inside the document.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I did print(soup) but I don't think I see it. It looks weird though, as the HTML in the terminal seems to be missing a lot of information (such as <divs). I can provide the link if that would help you.

Comment: @pchryss The `beautifulsoup` cannot get you the information that isn't there. You probably need to find other means to retrieve the information. Via `selenium` or using API (if there's any)

Comment: @AndrejKesely Interesting. Is there any explanation as to why I was able to scrape the information using the id attribute but not the data-row? It found the exact contents I needed and put them into a spreadsheet. Thank-you for your help though!